# Update an object with matching properties and ignore new properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm using Typescript and I would like to update an object with another, only on the matching keys.

```js
// Destination
objectOne = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
};

// Source
objectTwo = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1,
};

// Expected
result = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
};

// Current solution
const current = {};
Object.keys(objectTwo).forEach(key => key in objectOne ? current[key] = objectTwo[key] : null);

console.log(current);
```

is there a one-liner ***(i.e. not a custom function that iterates over the keys)*** that would ignore the property `c` in the source ? I would also like to avoid using libraries such as lodash or JQuery.

**Duplicate EDIT** my question isn't about merging two objects, my question is about ignoring the fields in the second object, that aren't in the first object.

Comment: @Mium not at all. I'm not trying to join them. I'm trying to ignore the new fileds, which is the exact opposite of the question you quoted.

Comment: IMHO, your solution is pretty short and readable, that's what I do too in such cases. Let's see, is there more brief way...

Comment: @CommercialSuicide That's the shorter I've found, but I expected something signed like `Object.assign` ...

Comment: What about this `Object.keys(objectOne).reduce((r,k) =>
     (r[k] = k in objectTwo ? objectTwo[k] : objectOne[k], r) , {});` ?

Comment: @Hassan this is basically the same thing as my current solution, which is a custom function, something I would like to avoid

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: Have you tried like this `for(var i in objectOne) { current[i] = objectTwo[i] }`

Comment: @DavidJawHpan this is longer than my current solution, and it's still a custom function

Comment: @RobC first of all that's not true, if you put `y: 10` in the first object and merge the second object in it, the `y` property will be kept. Second, if we assume it is indeed false, that's besides the question, since I asked to update only the existing fields with the keys of the second object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a while without answers, it seems the shortest solution is the one I provided myself :

```
Object.keys(newObj).forEach(key => key in oldObj? result[key] = newObj[key] : null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = Object.keys(objectOne)
    .reduce((init, key) => Object.assign(init, {[key]: objectTwo[key]}) , {});
```

Comment: Again, this is a custom function, something I would like to avoid. What I would like is a built-in function such as `Object.assign`, but it ignores the new fields.

Comment: Didn't notice your edit, so the answer is irrelevant

Comment: Still, keep it there, as it might help someone looking for it !

Comment: This fails if `objectOne` has properties that `objectTwo` doesn't, making those properties `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no built-in function to accomplish what you need, rather than a custom one with iterating over keys of the first object and values of the second one:

```
const objectOne = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0
};

const objectTwo = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1,
};

const result = Object.keys(objectOne).reduce((all, key) => {

    all[key] = objectTwo[key] || objectOne[key];

    return all;

},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Okay, so the best I can do is stay with my current solution ... thank you for the tip