# How to assign an object with more fields to another object with less fields without adding extra fields to first object?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I have an object as:

```js
secondObject {
  name: value,
  userName: value,
  userId; value,
}
```

And I have a pre-defined Model whose instance I am creating as

```js
let modelObject: Model.
```

The Model is defined as follows

```js
{
  userName,
  userId
}
```

Basically both models have some common fields and same data type since the first object I have described is just an extension of a join query on the Model and some other data, resulting into having an object that has all the fields of the Model plus some more.

What I want to do is:-

```js
let thirdObj: Model;
obj = object
```

The 'object' above is one with the extra fields

and **NOT** get the obj as:

```js
{
      name: null,
      userName: value,
      userId; value,
    }
```

But instead GET:

```js
{
userName: value,
userId: value
}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update an object with matching properties and ignore new properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206836/update-an-object-with-matching-properties-and-ignore-new-properties)

Comment: Try spead operator