# Typescript constructors - Ignore fields that don't exist on target

Tags: angular

I love using the Partial constructor pattern in my class constructors like so..

```
export class TestClass {
  prop1: string = null;
  prop2: string = null;

  public constructor(init?: Partial<TestClass>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

This is great for dumping partial objects from eg a form. The trouble is when I pass an object to this constructor that has fields not defined in the class, they are added anyway.

```
const testObj = {prop1= '', prop2 = '', prop3 = 'Don't apply me!'}
const newObj = new TestClass(testObj)
```

So here newObj contains prop3.

Is there some way to stop this behaviour, i.e. only add fields that exist on the class?

I saw that [user4676340](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206836/update-an-object-with-matching-properties-and-ignore-new-properties) ask a similar question and had the following custom code

```
Object.keys(objectTwo).forEach(key => key in objectOne ? current[key] = objectTwo[key] : null);
```

Is there a nice 'TypeScript way' to do this, if not how can I implement something like the above in a constructor?

Thanks

Comment: No, there's no typescript way to do this, because typescript *doesn't exist* at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for now I'm gonna use this method which seems to work...Let me know if anyone knows of a better way

```
        public constructor(init?: any) {
        Object.keys(init).forEach((key) =>
            key in this ? (this[key] = init[key]) : null
        );
```